# How to covert comma separated string to a 2D array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

For example I have some comma separated strings
"aron, IA52, 20"
"john, IA61, 23"
"kleo, IA32, 42"
How can I convert them to a 2 dimensional array in the easiest way possible?

Comment: Do you know about `split()`, which can convert _one_ string to a _1-dimensional_ array?

Comment: Hi, Could you please provide some details on what's the input like? Is it an array of strings or list of comma separated strings?

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in comments, you should use `split()` while iterating over your comma separated string list and populate your array accordingly. Here is sample code to give you some idea:

```java
List<String> input = Arrays.asList("aron, IA52, 20", "john, IA61, 23", "kleo, IA32, 42");
String[][] array = new String[3][3];
int row = 0;

// Loop Over Comma Separated List and split each string to populate 2D array
for (String commaSeparatedStr : input) {
    String[] parts = commaSeparatedStr.split(",");
    System.arraycopy(parts, 0, array[row], 0, parts.length);
    row++;
}

// Print array
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        System.out.print(array[i][j]);
    System.out.println();
}
```

This prints:

```
aron IA52 20
john IA61 23
kleo IA32 42
```

Comment: What gave you the idea that the input is a `List`? I fail to see that in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I don't see input type specified in the question. Let me ask OP for

Answer (score 0):

The provided function will parse the string to the 2D matrix.
Below is the format of the string that you need to provide to this function.

```
1.2,2.3,3.5\n3.1,4.70,5.0
```

**function**

```
public double[][] parseStingToArray(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
        String arr1[] = str.split("\n");

        double[][] ans = new double[arr1.length][];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            String[] col = arr1[i].split(",");
            ans[i] = new double[col.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                ans[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(col[j]);
            }
        }

        doubleArray = ans;
        return ans;
    }
```